# Writing A Bot Framework Client

Tags: botframework

I've been away from BotFramework development for a while and have now come back to it.

I am using this Bot hosted internally within my company, and talking to it using a relay application using REST. This all worked fine.

However, after updating to V3 of the Bot Framework I came across issues. I see that the changes mean that the Bot now replies asynchronously, sending data to the ServiceURL field. Therefore I have a couple of questions.

1. Can I still use this architecture for the Bot Framework? (i.e. hosting internally to the company, without using Azure or Connectors)
2. If I can, I assume that my relay application will need to have an endpoint that the Bot can reply to? Does it just do a http POST to the ServiceUrl I give it? (i.e. http://mybotserver:9000) or is it posting to a URL under that server address? I assume the body of the post is the usual Json you see in the Channel Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of your architecture, but in general, if your bot (via relay) can:

1. Reach the ServiceURL endpoint with an https post
2. Receive incoming requests to an endpoint you registered with the Bot Framework
3. The relay needs to be able to reach our login service to sign requests
4. Also needs to be able to reach our OpenId endpoint as part of signing/authenticating

That should be it.

Comment: So in other words, if we are hosting the bot internally (behind a company firewall for intranet apps) we have to open a port in the firewall for it to go out and get authenticated? If company policies do not allow this, is there a way to use the bot framework any other way?

Comment: Ok looks like this is not possible :( https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/faq/#is-it-possible-for-me-to-build-a-bot-using-the-bot-frameworksdk-that-is-a-private-or-enterprise-only-bot-that-is-only-available-inside-my-company

Comment: This is pretty disappointing. Definitely invalidates a ton of use cases.